# Remove All Space Between Loading Bars - ngx-skeleton-loader - Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm working in a Angular11 project that's using material and ngx-skeleton-loader.

I have some loading bars that I want to style. I want to remove all spacing between the bars. However, even if I set the margin and padding to 0px, there's still some spacing between the bars.
It's a very small amount of space, but I still want it gone.
[image]

I tried adding a theme of `'margin': '0px', 'padding': '0px'`, and it removed most of the spacing, but not all.
Even if I use dev tools and inspect the element, it shows as having no margin or padding, but the space is still there:

[image]

How can I get rid of the space?

Here's a stackblitz I whipped up: https://stackblitz.com/edit/remove-space-between-loaders?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `margin-bottom: -4px !important;` in the `loader` css class.

Result:
[image]

Comment: You can use -4.5px or -5px to get more precise result, maybe.

Comment: Haha, can't believe I didn't think of using negative margin to offset the space. This works! TY!